# Logout from Kinde SDK is broken... App can't read auth state when user logs out

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm using next.js 14 and Kinde Auth for a B2B app requiring basic organizations logic. Now, when I log out using the provided React Components, the app freezes and cannot read Authentication state.
Any one using kinde ?

[Client Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/codU8.png)
Server Error :

```
 ⨯ Error: Cannot get user details, no authentication credential found
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/.pnpm/@kinde-oss+kinde-typescript-sdk@2.6.2/node_modules/@kinde-oss/kinde-typescript-sdk/dist/sdk/clients/server/authorization-code.js:310:35)
```

Would appreciate any help

I've tried upgrading to the latest Kinde Auth SDK

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.